# treesitter/highlighter issues with LaTeX formula in Markdown files, and any other language

Tags: latex, markdown, syntax-highlighting, neovim, treesitter

[treesitter/highlighter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q37es.png)

I am getting these treesitter/highlighter errors with markdown files too when I write a formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I installed, Lua5.4, tree-sitter-cli, complete latex, python3-venv, completely removed and reinstalled neovim.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting might be caused by multiple parser paths, with the incorrect version being used. You can check the paths of the parser files by running the following command in Nvim:
`:echo nvim_get_runtime_file('parser', v:true)`
Check the parser path if the path isn't a valid path then
install markdown parser `:TSInstall vimdoc`

As from this [github issue](https://github.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/issues/3680), try `TSUpdate`, I prefer you to read the whole comments

Comment: `:TSUpdate all` worked. Rip modularity, I guess.